# How to use bootstrap.css to generate PDF in Grails

Tags: intellij-idea, grails, groovy, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am working on a [Grails-5](https://grails.org/) project. To export data in PDF format I am using [rendering plugin](https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/rendering). Everything works well but when I include the bootstrap.css in the page header e.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox cannot be cast to org.xhtmlrenderer.newtable.TableBox
```

Below is the code.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is going to work out of the box.  It looks like `XHTMLlRenderer` library has limitations on CSS it recognizes, and Bootstrap is going to be super modern compared to what XHTMLRenderer supports.  It appears that it doesn't understand how to render say a `TableBox` vs a `BlockBox`.  So I suspect doing this in CSS is not supported with XHTMLRenderer.

```
.someClass {
   display: table;
}
```

I know HTML tables are supported with XHTMLRenderer because I use them extensively for PDF creation, but support for taking a non-table tag like `div` and setting it's display to table is questionable at best.

You'll probably have to trim out sections from bootstrap with the rules you with use and create a subset of bootstrap for usage.